# How to keep only the highly significant variables in r and combine two entire corpus to make predictions?

Tags: r, analytics, logistic-regression, corpus, text-analysis

I'm using R and I have a file of blog posts with 3 variables: **title** (the title of the post), **body** (the text of the post) and **great** (1 if the post received five stars, 0 otherwise). I already created a corpus for the title, remove punctuation, converted it to lowercase, etc. as follows:

```
title = Corpus(VectorSource(posts$title))
title = tm_map(title, tolower)
title = tm_map(title, PlainTextDocument)
title = tm_map(title, removePunctuation)
title = tm_map(title, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
title = tm_map(title, stemDocument)
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(title)
sparseTerms = removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)
title = as.data.frame(as.matrix(sparseTerms))
title$great = posts$great
```

I did the same process for the **body** variable. After that, I used `sample.split` to separate a training and a testing set (for the title) and used the `glm()` function to use a logistic regression:

```
library(caTools)
spl = sample.split(title$great, 0.7)
train = subset(title, spl = TRUE)
test = subset(title, spl = FALSE) 
Log = glm(great ~ ., data=train, family=binomial)
summary(Log)
```

Now when I use `summary()` I can see which variables are significant (3 stars). And, as you can see, I only used the **title** variable at `glm()`. So I'd like to know:

1. How to keep only the variables with 3 stars?
2. How to combine the title and the body corpus so that I can use the glm() function with all the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the object returned by `summary(...)$coefficients`, you'll see that it is just a matrix with the intercept and predictors as row names and with `Estimate`, `Std. Error`, `z value`, and `Pr(>|z|)` as column names. The column name you're interested in is the last (fourth). Using the name you created for the logistic model in your code:

```
# Get the coefficient matrix
coefs <- summary(Log)$coefficients

# Identify the variables with "3 stars"
vars <- rownames(coefs)[which(coefs[, 4] < 0.001)]
```

As for your second question: a simple way of combining two (small to moderate sized) data frames in the way you're talking about is to use `cbind`.